# How can I prove non-geometrically that there is a bijective correspondence between polar and cartesian representations of coordinates?

Tags: coordinate-systems, polar-coordinates

We have a function $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ as $f(x,y) = (\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$, $\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right))$ which takes a Cartesian pair $(x,y)$ to its polar form, and a function $g: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ as $g(r,\theta) = (r\cos\theta, r\sin\theta)$, which takes a polar pair $(r, \theta)$ to its Cartesian representation.

I'm having trouble proving that there's a bijective correspondence between the two representations.  It is easy to show, for instance, that $f \circ g = \text{id}_{\mathbb{R}^2}$, but not quite as easy to show the other direction.

Any hints or help would be appreciated.

--

Edit:  I have also tried messing around with injectivity and surjectivity between the two functions, so that the one-way composition-identity equality suffices to prove that the two functions are inverses.  But I run into the same problems, which the below answer resolves by using trig identities.  Is there a way to circumvent this?

Comment: Have you restricted $r$ and $\theta$ at all?

Comment: Yes, I also have assumed that $r\ge 0$ and $-\pi < \theta < \pi$.

Comment: There is no bijective correspondence if you allow $r=0$. If $r=0$ then $\theta$ can be anything without changing the point.

Comment: The function is not defined for $x=0$. You need to use something like $\operatorname{arg}$ (or $\operatorname{atan2}$) instead, and you need to remove $(0,0)$ from the domain.

Comment: Note that the way $f_2$ is defined does not distinguish between $(x,y)$ and $-(x,y)$.

Comment: Yeah, my bounds were kind of screwed up.

Comment: On that note, if there is an alternative to using inverse trig identities and showing $g \circ f = \text{id}_{\mathbb{R}^2}$, I would love to explore it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Substitute $r= \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and $\theta = arctan(\frac{y}{x})$ into $g$ and use the Relations for [inverse trigonometric functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions).